# Content types inherited from Folder content type with Publishing image field

Tags: content-type, publishing, image

I've a custom content MyAlbum type inherits from Folder content type, MyAlbum has a publishing image field, I've![enter image description here][1] bounded MyAlbum to new list from Document library template, i couldn't add any item from this content type, in New form i choose an image and enter a name in Name field, when i click save, nothing happens, the name field got cleared and no message at all appears.

Answer (score 0):

A field like this does not belong in a folder content type. Create an item content type instead. Why do you need a Publishing Image field? This is designed to be used in a Publishing Library and gets special attention with the respective Page Layout.

What are you trying to achieve? Select the correct content type for that purpose.